# How to copy text from a messageBox in Visual Basic / VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I copy text from a messageBox in Visual Basic?

I know I could just do Ctr+C and it would copy the text, the problem with this technique is that it copies the title and the button text as well and in my case I only want to copy the numeric value .0006734, any idea how can I accomplish this?

FYI - It needs to be done programmatically due to some UI limitations.

Here is the code I'm currently using for the message box.

```
MessageBox.Show("Yields :  " + CStr(totalYields), "Yields X")
```

[image]

Comment: since *your code* passed the text to the MessageBox, why cant you store it to a variable?  In fact you already have the numeric value in `totalYields` dont you?

Comment: You want to do this?: `Clipboard.SetText("Yields :  " & CStr(totalYields))`

Comment: Not an answer, but to do this in Windows the keyboard shortcut is `ctrl` + `shift` + `Ins`

Comment: Are you by chance trying to get information from a message box generated by an **external** application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå -

This works, copying it to the clipboard was also an option. Thanks a lot

```
Clipboard.SetText( CStr(totalYields))
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: This may be the best answer using a standard *.NET* "MessageBox", but I think the ideal solution would be a message box that works like those displayed by Visual Studio where the user can mark any part or all of the text in them as if all the text were in some borderless read-only TextBox on the Form.  I think Microsoft developed some custom "MessageBox" for that that they're not sharing with us in .NET.